# Using Ctrl+Shift+T in IntelliJ to jump to test files for JavaScript

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea

Is there a way to enable the Ctrl+Shift+T (Jump to test file) shortcut for JavaScript files?

It works great for Java files, but doesn't seem to work for JavaScript files.

Answer (score 0):

It's enabled in 2017.1+. Linking is based on test files/folders names, e.g. performing `Navigate | Test` inside a file named `My.js` will navigate you to `MySpec.js` file.
Patterns are hardcoded to `*Spec.js`, `*_spec.js`, `*-spec.js`,  `*.spec.*` (+same patterns with "test" instead of "spec").
Also, it works for relative paths, e.g. it will navigate from "my-app/src/main/javascript/acme/Foo.js" to "my-app/test/main/javascript/acme/Foo.js" (or "my-app/src/test/javascript/acme/Foo.js", or "my-app/src/main/test/acme/Foo.js", etc.)

Comment: Interesting. I guess I'll have to play around with it. I was trying myfile.spec.js and myfile.test.js in the same folder, and in a mirrored structure between src and test (both marked appropriately) and it didn't seem to do anything. I'm using the latest version of IntelliJ.